# How to convert binary file -> font asset in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fonts, binary

I have a .ttf file and I used `File.ReadAllBytes`
So, Can I convert this binary datas as Font Class in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make the font as a binary file? There must be some online tool that can do that for you.

Fonts that you can use in unity (as a font asset):

https://fonts.google.com/

Comment: Because I'm trying to load a font from outside the Unity Assets folder.

Comment: then put the font inside the assets folder